# Android Studio Gradle project "Unable to start the daemon process /initialization of VM"

Tags: java, android, jvm, daemon, beta

Version of Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.4
OS version: Windows 8
Java JRE/JDK version: 1.8.0_11

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.12/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1048576KB object heap
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Comment: I tried many approaches WO success. What helped whas when I replaced the embedded JDK (which is recommended :) for another JDK - I installed appart. 'File->ProjectStructure-> JDK Location'
 It could be, that my embedded JDK is somehow corrupt.

Answer (score 184):

The Solution Worked:

  1.Open the projects
  **gradle.properties**
  file in android studio

  2.Added this line at end of file
  **org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m**
  & Save the file

  3.Close & reopen the project or just Clean and re-Build it

Comment: Close & reopen the project is not mandatory, You can just CleanBuild it

Comment: This is low level memory problem and also 32bit environment problem where is not possible to alocate so much memory for the heap. In your project check **gradle.properties** (and if needed use lower number **org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m**). This may be necessary if the project was created on 64bit system. Then set lower default in your Android Studio as mentioned below as it should take precedence (File > Close Project, then Configure > Settings -> Build, Execution, Environment > Android Compilers > VM Options > **-Xmx512m**).

Comment: this worked for me, i was previously increasing the heap which did not work. only worked when i decreased the heap. thanks for sharing.

Comment: i had "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m" already;
still had the issue. i resolved and answered;

Comment: what if this line was already there?

Answer (score 41):

Do Following steps:

1. Start Android Studio.
2. Close any open project.Go to File > Close Project.(Welcome window will open)
3. Go to Configure > Settings.
4. On Settings dialog,select **Compiler (Gradle-based Android
   Projects)** from left and set VM Options to **-Xmx512m**(i.e. write -Xmx512m
   under VM Options:) and press OK.

[image: Where to put it]

Comment: What is the explanation for this ?

Comment: @Giru Bhai can you add a screenshot as to where exactly we have to write -Xmx512m

Comment: In my android studio Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects) not showing only.

Comment: I am using android studio 2.3.3 and not able to see VM Options under the compiler. any help ?

Comment: @KingofMasses Check here  https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html for Customize your VM options

Comment: i added this after closing all projects; still had the issue. i resolved and answered;

Answer (score 32):

I had the same issue, it was because I had an existing ".gradle" folder and then I've played with the android studio version (and also with the Java jdk version) , and I guess it messed things up.

Solution: Remove the .gradle directory (mine's location was C:\Users\UserName\.gradle), and restart android studio. It will automatically create a new one.

Comment: This worked however my ".gradle" folder wasn't located under users. To find the location of of your ".gradle" folder, in Android Studio goto File->Settings and type "gradle" in the search box. You will be able to pick up the correct path there.

Comment: One other thing. Gradle does not like UNC paths. So if your path starts with \\ you will need to move your ".gradle" dir to another location.

Comment: my .gradle folder size is 5.2 Gbyte

Comment: though i had tried this previously; still faced the issue. i resolved and answered;

Answer (score 16):

For android studio 2.2 version VM option is not available directly from project structure.

steps to make gradle sync successful:->

1)OPEN project

2)Click on gradle script

3)open gradle.properties

4)Change org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m to org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m

5)Save the work

6)Open File->Invalidate cache/Restart

And its done!!!

Enjoy Android!!!

Answer (score 15):

Open your project and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> to open **Project Structure**. There under **JDK location** check `Use embedded JDK (recommended)`.

Comment: Worked for AS 3.0 beta 2. Thanks

Comment: After Android Studio 3.5 update, In first open it suggest me to change JDK location as same as gradle. 
When I back to embedded JDK, The Problem solved!

Answer (score 9):

Just **reboot your PC**

Not sure what caused this issue for me, I've tried all the solutions here, nothing worked.
Reboot helped, Windows 7.

*org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m* was already there.

### Update:

I believe it started after Update of Windows Defender Antivirus (KB915597)

Approximate date of update - 2018.07.22

Answer (score 5):

It has to do with how much memory is available for AS to create a VM environment for your app to populate. The thing is that ever since the update to 2.2 I've had the same problem every time I try to create a new project in AS.

How I solve it is by going into **Project (on the left hand side) > Gradle Scripts > gradle.properties**. When it opens the file go to the line under "(Line 10)# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process. (Line 11)# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings." You're looking for the line that starts with *"org.gradle.jvmargs"*. This should be line 12. Change line 12 to this

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

After changing this line you can either sync the gradle with the project by clicking Try again on the notification telling you the gradle sync failed (it'll be at the top of the file you opened). Or you can simply close and restart the AS and it should sync.

Essentially what this is saying is for AS to **allocate more memory to the app** initialization. I know it's not a permanent fix but it should get you through actually starting your app.

Answer (score 5):

**the heap-size was already set** in project and also android studio.
still, had this issue.

this issue is related to memory size.
**here is what solved my issue**:

1. open "task management" in windows(ctrl + shift + esc)
   check, whether any program is eating memory.
   **please scroll down**
   (first time i just saw according to descending order of memory usage. but scrolled after trying other options and realised, "openjdk platform binary" consumed around 50mb **but** was running around more than 50 instances.)
   [image]
2. end all the instances and check whether it solves the issue.
   **if "yes",** **update java** so that, starting all these multiple instance entries are wiped out of registry.
   **if "no"**, try following:

additional solutions (if heap-size was already set):

1. **uninstall** any lastly (recently) installed plugin.
   if you want the plugin (search for plugin related issue).
2. File>**Invalidate caches** / restart...
3. update gradle.
4. uninstall android studio and install a fresh new one (after File>Manage IDE settings>Export to ZIP files).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Starting Android Studio as Administrator fixed it.

Comment: how can I unlink Gradle, Do I need to download Latest Gradle Update??

Comment: Not working, same error occurs. Android studio version 1.3.1

Answer (score 4):

Open Android Studio then go to gradle.properties file and change the last line to

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m.

And then press try again

Answer (score 3):

Open Android Studio then go to gradle.properties  file and change the last line to

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m.
```

then go to

> File>Invalidate Caches/Restart.

and the problem will be solved, it worked fine with me.

Answer (score 3):

In some PC's this issue is caused by antivirus programs AFTER upgrading to the latest android studio and gradle version.

In my case I tore my system apart troubleshooting everything only to find out that Commodo Internet security was responsible for not letting the gradle daemon run.

After safelisting the process everything runs smoothly.
PLEASE NOTE that everything was OK before updating. The issue came up only after the update without changing anything in the antivirus/firewall program.

Comment: I tried each and everything but your solution worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, bear in mind that the same thing may happen again for newer updates (as program version changes) or when you run gradle commands from cmd. Make sure you whitelist your Android studio path in the containment settings and HIPS rules in Comodo.

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you went into a little detail on HOW to safelist the process. I realise everyone uses a different AV, but what is the specific process to safelist? Thanks.

Comment: @Utkanos I would suggest instead of wasting time and mind essence to make comments on how an answer -should- be to think a little bit beforehand or just ask politely...especially when such an easy answer is a google search away... check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41787197/how-to-allow-android-studio-to-connect-to-internet-via-windows-firewall/41787668#41787668)
or just press ctrl+alt+delete in Windows when android studio is running right click the Android Studio app and select "open file location" that will show you name and path of the file to whitelist :)

Comment: @GiorgosS. - I'm afraid you've taken my comment too defensively. SO is ALL about questions and answers, and a voting system exists precisely because some answers are better than others. Comments are here to seek clarification and advise on how answers or questions could be improved. This really isn't controversial. Don't take things personally. It's just a plain fact - your answer would be better with the missing info.

Comment: @Utkanos I think you misunderstood me,my original answer was to complement the existing content of the thread and my comment wasn't towards a personal defense but rather on a specific way of thinking. I absolutely agree on what you wrote about SO but "spoonfeeding" on certain trivial matters first and foremost doesn't apply for everyone's configuration and secondly doesn't help anyone learn on his own.
So a complete guide would be even better than what you suggest but here would be out of scope. Therefore I prefer to link an answer to extend the info just in case someone is still in doubt  :)

Comment: Fair enough. We can agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue , i just remove .gradle file and restart android studio, it automatically download latest version and it works perfect.....

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `-Xmx512m` in `Android Studio->Settings->Compiler->VM Options` as in below image.

***Reason for this issue could be:*** Grade's build daemon ( forked process ) is invoked with maximum Java heap size as [platform default](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html#wp1035652) value. On a 32 bit  Windows this system this could be as high as 1GB. We get this error message, if that much(default) heap size cannot be allocated to the build deamon. So use the `-Xmx` option to set a lower heap size. It is not necessary to stick to `-Xmx<size>` with size as `512m`. In my Win 32bit, 4GB RAM machine, `-Xmx768m` was also good enough.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately i have now downloaded the stable version of Android Studio and it is working gud :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, what i found was that Android Developer tools doesn't work well with JDK 8.
I deleted my current JDK 8 and and installed JDK 7 and worked just like that no increase of heap memory or delete of .gradle folder.

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, I *just* encountered this sudden problem after performing a Windows Update on Windows 10. Somehow, that update messed up my existing Malwarebytes Anti-Exploit program, and ultimately caused Android Studio to be unable to invoke the JVM (I couldn't even open cmd.exe!).

Solution was to remove the Malwarebytes Anti-Exploit program (this may be fixed in the future).

Answer (score 2):

I got same problem and I solved it using these steps.

1)Remove your .gradle file.(uuslly it in C:\Users{your_PC_name}

2)then go to the environment variable and add these to the system variable(as a new variable)

Variable name : _JAVA_OPTIONS

Variable value: -Xmx524m

3)go to your project folder and run these command

> ionic cordova platform add android

4)Above command create platform folder in your project path

5)then run this command

> ionic cordova build android

Answer (score 2):

I've just cleaned up my disk space and restart computer. That have helped me.

Answer (score 2):

If i can help you, you have to go in the Project Properties, and in the JDK location field check **Use embedded JSD (recommended)** eneable.

Answer (score 2):

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap.

To solve this error you have to change only heap size which is defined in Gradle.Properties file. You have to change the heapsize to 1024m and rebuild the project.

If the error is not solved, you have to close the project and rebuild it.

For Video Tutorial: [Unable To Start The Daemon Process In Android Studio](https://youtu.be/rEVWb_8XmLU)

Comment: My problem still persists

Answer (score 1):

Different solutions may work

1. Delete `.gradle` folder from `c:\users\username\.gradle`
2. `File` > `Settings`.
   On Settings dialog, select `Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects)` from left and set VM Options to `-Xmx512m` (i.e. write `-Xmx512m` under VM Options:) and press `OK`.
3. Close multiple applications running on your machine and clear memory space and try again

Answer (score 1):

- Start Android Studio.
- Close any open project.Go to File > Close Project.(Welcome window will open)
- Go to Configure > Settings.
- On Settings dialog,select Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects) from left and set VM Options to -Xmx512m(i.e. write -Xmx512m under VM Options:) and press OK.

It mostly works for that initilize vm problem.

Answer (score 1):

Start Android Studio.
Close any open project.Go to File > Close Project.(Welcome window will open)
Go to Configure > Settings.
On Settings dialog,select Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects) from left and set VM Options to -Xmx512m(i.e. write -Xmx512m under VM Options:) and press OK.

and then do this

Right click on My Computer and Open up your System Properties (The bit you had open before that shows your CPU/RAM values) >> On the left sidebar, click Advanced System Settings >> Click Environment Variables >> Under System Variables, press New >> Use the values below: // Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS // Variable value: -Xmx524M then, press OK and try again. restart Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling firewall.

This might be a very weird solution but I had the same problem and I'm running Android 2.3 on windows 32 bit . I deleted the current app and disabled firewall. Upon creating a new project everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the path to environment variables (Windows) like such:

```
Variable Name: GRADLE_HOME
Variable Value: path
```

Please check below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to adding -Xmx512m in Android Studio->Settings->Compiler->VM Options , it's working thanks..

Comment: Open up your System Properties (The bit you had open before that shows your CPU/RAM values) >> On the left sidebar, click Advanced System Settings >> Click Environment Variables >> Under System Variables, press New >> Use the values below:

// Variable name:
_JAVA_OPTIONS
// Variable value:
-Xmx524M

then, press OK and try again. restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

In the `gradle.properties` file, change `org.gradle.jvmargs` to `-Xmx1024m`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=**-Xmx1024m** -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

My case is a bit special which VM option is not avaibale. I use x86 windows 7 system, my way of solving this problem is by doing following procedures:

1. File - Setting...
2. In "Build, Execution, Deployment" select "Gradle"
3. choose "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" in "Project-level settings"

After restart Android Studio problem fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I think if your environment just got messed up because of some VCS merging or commit errors, which is my case, i would suggest you just re-import your porject and add it to the root of your VCS to restore the project. If you use a VCS like git  or subversion, you'll simply have to add your project to the root of the given repo and everything should be back to normal.
This worked for me though.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by installing JDK x64. I guess you're using jdk x86 and it's not enough memory for gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Just installed new version of gradle and it started working for me. I think the local instances of gradle were messed up

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me because i was running a virtual machine at the same time, the ram was already allocated to that so android studio couldn't take up any ram, switching off virtual box and restarting did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

File->Settings->compiler->check - Compile independent modules in parallel(may require larger heap size)

**gradle.properties**

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx768m

add this end of the file.

it works for me.

if Not, uncheck - Compile independent modules in parallel, and set org.gradle.jvmargs=Xmx768m like above

Answer (score 0):

Simply you could change the gradle.properties . i have given the sample below[image]

Answer (score 0):

Different solutions work for different people. I have tried almost all the solutions posted above and on other forums.

In my case, the problem was occurring because the **Mobile Hotspot feature** was enabled on my laptop.

Laptop Configuration:
-Windows 10
-RAM 12GB
-Android Studio 4.2.2
-Gradle version 6.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Go to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines, make sure you do not have anything unnecessary. In my case, I accidentally installed jdk-19.jdk, I wanted to use zulu-11.jdk. Deleting jdk-19.jdk solved my problem. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It was strange for me to kill ADB process from task list and try again, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my situation was related to the Hotspot being enabled on my laptop. Once I turned off the Hotspot and ran the project, it worked successfully.

Answer (score -1):

I faced This problem, so I solve it with **remove the project folder** and **recreate the new project.**

The above solution worked for me, hope to help anyone.