# Android Studio (IntelliJ) Error Message

Tags: java, android, eclipse, intellij-idea

After I have created a new project in the latest Android Studio (IntelliJ), I got an error message:

> Moverover, how to bring out the UI in the Android studio (IntelliJ) which was previously in the Android Eclipse?

Gradle `FirstApp` project refresh failed:

Error: `Unable to start the daemon process.`

This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized JVM option is used.
Please refer to the user [guide chapter](http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html) on the daemon.

Please read the following process output to find out more:

> 21:05:33.924 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - Assuming the daemon was started with following jvm opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1024m, -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252, -Duser.country=NZ, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.variant]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not create service of type DaemonContext using DaemonServices.createDaemonContext().
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Comment: Restart Android Studio? (or IntellIJ IDEA, which one you use?)

Comment: I've restarted several times, problem still exist. The latest Android Studio uses IntelliJ, previous Android Studio was associated with Eclipse.

Comment: Remove `~\.gradle` directory (@home) and restart `AS`. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27516679/483588

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the Android Studio and run as administrator...

I had the same problem after updating Android Studio and this problem was resolved by running the Android Studio with administrator privilege.