# Gradle Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, virtual-machine

Hi i have a problem i see this in my android studio:

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused
>   by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an unrecognized
>   jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide chapter on the
>   daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>   Please read the following process output to find out more:
>   ----------------------- 23:57:48.187 [main] DEBUG o.g.l.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain - Assuming the daemon was started
>   with following jvm opts: [-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,
>   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xmx1256m, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Duser.country=SV, -Duser.language=es, -Duser.variant]
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not create service of type DaemonContext using DaemonServices.createDaemonContext().
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: That's nice. What's your question?

Comment: I have tried many methods but not to do 'm new to this and I served the android before but now that I 've opened it pulls me and i do not know what to do

Comment: You should rephrase what you ask in your original post as a question.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to Android Studio->Settings->Compiler->VM Options and set -Xmx512m

Reason for this issue could be: Grade's build daemon ( forked process ) is invoked with maximum Java heap size as platform default value in your case 1256MB

For more information check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio)