# Android studio is not working

Tags: android, android-studio

When I open my android studio it doesn't start any project in work space and give the error "Gradle MyApplication project refresh failed" with "Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:423)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClasspathUtil.getClasspathForClass(ClasspathUtil.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.findDistDir(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.<init>(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)
"
```

Comment: which AS version you use.

Comment: Android Studio 1.4.1

Comment: update your AS and gradle also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I have tired this. First deleting your .gradle file from C:\Users\ directory and start android studio again, if it doesn't work, try restarting studio.

Or

2. Try this.

Do Following steps:

Start Android Studio.
Close any open project.Go to File > Close Project.(Welcome window will open)
Go to Configure > Settings.
On Settings dialog,select Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects) from left and set VM Options to -Xmx512m(i.e. write -Xmx512m under VM Options:) and press OK.

[See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090752/2164477)

Comment: I delete .gradle  re-start studio it doesn't give any response what can I do for it.

Comment: @user3874188 Just wait until it completes downloading required things.

Comment: it is not download any thing when i re-start after deletion studio refresh an gives the same error. where is the downloading notification I didn't get it.

Comment: I have edited my answer, try the second option, check if it works.

Comment: @AkshayChauhan Please mention how you solved your problem, so that other can get help.