# Android Studio Gradle project “Unable to start the daemon process”

Tags: java, android, jvm, daemon

I am following this link  [Android Studio Gradle project "Unable to start the daemon process /initialization of VM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio) to solve my problem. The solution states that I open  Compiler (Gradle-based Android Projects), but i can't find this option anywhere. There is an image to show where is should make the changes but my left side of the panel look nothing like that. It has limited options. I followed exactly as told till the 3rd step but still my left side menu are completely different than in the picture. As of now i am adding "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m" to each of my project which is tedious. Could someone please tell me where that Compiler(Gradle-based Android Projects) is located at??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this.

1. File ->
2. Other Settings ->
3. Default Settings ->
4. Build, Execution, Deployment ->
5. Compiler

Then change `Build process heap size (Mbytes)` to 1024 and `Additional build process VM options` to -Xmx1024m.
Finally restart `Android Studio`.

Comment: this did not do the trick for me. I am using android studio 2.2.1. If you have any suggestion for this version please let me know. :)

Comment: Try Invalidate Caches/ Restart -> Invalidate and Restart a couple of times. It has worked for me for most of the times.

Comment: i shall try that. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

A **temporary** solution is to disable the firewall (or ajust some rules, which I don't know).

At least that helped me. I am still looking for a permanent solution. However, this is better than nothing for the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

i am facing this problem multiple time, whenever I invalidate and restart and then clean project and rebuilt all issues has been resolved.
this happened due to poor specification of pc or missing any of the recommendation of google android developers.