# android SDK gradle error

Tags: android, sdk

```
Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process.
         This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
         For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
         Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
         Please read the following process output to find out more:
         -----------------------
         Error occurred during initialization of VM
         Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
         Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

it displaying error when I am starting the android SDK. how to resolve it and thanks in advance. please apologize me if I made any grammatical or spelling mistakes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio

Comment: @Deepak Singh paazi you are right