# How to allow Android Studio to connect to internet via Windows Firewall?

Tags: android-studio, windows-firewall

I've Windows Firewall with Inbound and Outbound rules enabled. In android studio, I'm getting "Connection to the internet denied" error while gradle syncing etc. Already allowed studio.exe to connect in firewall but it's not working. If I disable firewall, it's able to connect. So in order to allow android studio to connect to internet without disabling windows firewall, what program should I add to windows firewall rules?

Comment: (I am not a Windows user) But try running Android studio as Administrator. Right click > Run as Admin.

Comment: @Enzokie it's already running as administrator. The issue is, some critical components are being blocked by windows firewall.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it by adding java.exe to Windows firewall inbound and outbound rules(in my case C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java.exe) and also studio.exe ( C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio.exe) to the rules. Then I was able to sync without disabling windows firewall. Hope it helps somebody..

Comment: Things change over time.  In 2019 the only exception I needed was Android Studio. (on my system at `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\studio64.exe`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to connect to internet through a company firewall, then you need to edit your **gradle.properties** file

`systemProp.http.proxyHost=XX.XX.XX.XX
systemProp.https.proxyPort=xxxx`