# android studio importing project error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
> This problem might be
> caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an
> unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide
> chapter on the daemon at
> https://docs.gradle.org/2.14.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
> Please
> read the following process output to find out more:
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM
> Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

Comment: Your project imported fine. Your computer doesn't have enough memory to build the project

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to Start-> Control Panel-> System-> Advanced(tab)-> Environment Variables-> System
Variables-> New:_JAVA_OPTIONS

Variable value: `-Xmx512M`

Variable name: `Path`
Variable value: `%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;F:\JDK\bin;`

Change this to your appropriate path.