# Android studio Gradle project refreshed failed encountered.How to recover fromit

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a Gradle project in which I have a problem with refreshing.
I cant even use the palette items or retrieve the phone type preview screen which i use in Eclipse.

The following screenshot depicts what I I experience. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Gradle project "Unable to start the daemon process /initialization of VM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio)

Answer (score 0):

Go to File menu on top, click on Invalidate Caches/restart and then select invalidate and restart. Hope it works for you as it solve my same issue before.