# Run lint command from android studio terminal?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-lint

When I execute below command

```
gradlew lint
```

I am facing this error:

> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 8 stopped Daemons could
>   not be reused, use --status for details
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example,
>   an unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide
>   chapter on the daemon at
>   https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
> Please read the following process output to find out more:
>
> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap
>
> Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   Starting Daemon

I could not understand anything from log, can someone have explain/solution to this issue.
I tried all comments/solutions given in [Android Studio Gradle project "Unable to start the daemon process /initialization of VM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio) , but not resolved .

Comment: This means you don't have enough heap size for gradle task.

Comment: Can you show your `gradle.properties`?

Comment: Which platform are you running Linux/mac/windows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Gradle project "Unable to start the daemon process /initialization of VM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio)

Comment: @Rinav , I am using Windows.

Comment: here is my gradle.properties file.  
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M

Comment: Try killing gradle: `./gradlew --stop` and then `./gradlew lint`.

Comment: since it is a android studio terminal so I run without `./` (`gradlew --stop` and then `gradlew lint`) but no luck. same error I observed.