# Unable to start the daemon process in android studio

Tags: java, android

I am finding this error again and again.I do uninstall and re install android studio but it's not working.Could anyone help in this issue please.The error message is like this:

Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

### Please read the following process output to find out more:

Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile you can try this

> 1.Open the projects gradle.properties file in android studio
>
> 2.Added this line at end of file org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m & Save the file
>
> 3.Close & reopen the project

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio)

Comment: i did all of these .But its not that problem.I went through stackoverflow on this issue but didn't find something helpful on my issue.