# Android Studio reports "Unable to start the daemon process"

Tags: java, android, gradle, daemon

I have searched the internet, trying to fix this and nothing has worked.

I have:

- deleted my .gradle folder and let Android Studio generate a new one,
- changed JVM options,
- changed Java global variables in Windows,
- updated sdk, ndk, jre, jdk, Android Studio and Windows
- changed file paths of these things so they don't have spaces.

and I can't get rid of this error in Android Studio.

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
```

And that's all it says. I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Gradle project "Unable to start the daemon process /initialization of VM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio)

Comment: what is the size of your pc memory ?

Comment: 8GB of ram and i dont think that it is a duplicate as i compleatly un installed everything to do with android studio (except my project) and then re-installed everything. even tried with a new project and still same issue

Comment: Fixed it. a fire wall was blocking the required connections... should have check there first really... thanx for your help guys! :D