# Changing the value of org.gradle.jvmargs fixes the "This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon." error

Tags: android, gradle

I was following this tutorial to use the Google Calendar API: https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java and I had to run this command:

```
gradle init --type basic
```

When I did, I received this error:

> Unable to start the daemon process.
>   This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.

I found in this question, [Android Studio Gradle project "Unable to start the daemon process /initialization of VM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio), that the answer was to add this line to the end of the gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

However, it gave me an error because I already had that property set, but to a different value, like so:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
```

I reran the gradle command without error and I was able to continue.

This question was answered almost 4 years ago. My project is new this week. Why would I have to use an older version in order for this to work? Also, what exactly is happening when I switch the value of org.gradle.jvmargs to another value?

Answer (score 0):

this setting controls the size of heap memory, which is available to the Gradle [daemon](https://guides.gradle.org/performance/#daemon)

meanwhile `1024M` is the default (at times of that answer `512M` might have been the default).

I have a project, which demands `5084M` to build. it ordinary complains when it's too less

... at least when setting option `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`.