# Gradle Building Failure & Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, build.gradle

I've been struggling with this problem, ofc I googled it but I am out of options. I re-installed Android Studio and Flutter SDK but no work. But I can start from scratch if you write the steps maybe I forgot something, I am not sure spending 4 hours with this I think I lost my mind.

```
* Error running Gradle:

ProcessException: Process "D:\flutter-workspace\test1\test1\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1536M
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1536M
  Command: D:\flutter-workspace\test1\test1\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
Exited (sigterm)
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

build.gradle
(the important part I think)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
```

.iml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="android" name="Android">
      <configuration>
        <option name="ALLOW_USER_CONFIGURATION" value="false" />
        <option name="GEN_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH_APT" value="/gen" />
        <option name="GEN_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH_AIDL" value="/gen" />
        <option name="MANIFEST_FILE_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" />
        <option name="RES_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/res" />
        <option name="ASSETS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/assets" />
        <option name="LIBS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/libs" />
        <option name="PROGUARD_LOGS_FOLDER_RELATIVE_PATH" value="/app/src/main/proguard_logs" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <exclude-output />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/app/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/gen" isTestSource="false" generated="true" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 25 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Flutter for Android" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio

Comment: nah it isn't, I fixed the problem. For people who are having this problem and couldn't find any solution yet, I had a username with non-English character and with whitespace, the place I bought my computer gave the username and without format (changing the user name I mean) it may confuse the register.

Answer (score 1):

For people who are having this problem and couldn't find any solution yet, I had a username with non-English character and with whitespace, the place I bought my computer gave the username and without format (changing the user name I mean) it may confuse the register.