# ERROR: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon

Tags: java, android, gradle

I tried almost all tricks but cannot fix this problem please anyone help

> ERROR: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be
>   caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an
>   unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the User Manual
>   chapter on the daemon at
>   https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Process
>   command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe
>   -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\dell.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.4.1-all\3221gyojl5jsh0helicew7rwx\gradle-5.4.1\lib\gradle-launcher-5.4.1.jar
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.4.1 Please read
>   the following process output to find out more:

---

Comment: Is it the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio ?

Answer (score 2):

Open `gradle.properties` after scrolling down.
Copy the following text and try building the program.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512m
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution 
Open `gradle.properties` and add this line

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX\:MaxPermSize\=512m
```

If this didn't solve your problem just go under `C:\Users\<username>` and delete `.gradle` directory then try building again.

Comment: when i disabled my antivirus software and try to sync it worked!! but everytime i should disable antivirus when syncing. Is there any way out?

Comment: Well can you try with your Antivirus activated but change this , go to `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle` and check offline work and use local gradle distribution. PS: Accept the answer if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I changed gradle.properties and it helped to solve same error, but after reload I am back to square ONE.

Unsupported Modules Detected: Compilation is not supported for following modules: capacitor-cordova-android-plugins. Unfortunately you can't have non-Gradle Java modules and Android-Gradle modules in one project.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had to remove the value "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m" in:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3g -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

In the file gradle.properties.

I run Intellij with openjdk-17.0.2

After that, It works Ok,