# Flutter error Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: flutter, gradle, build.gradle

My flutter project is run smoothly in my old laptop. But when I use my new laptop, my flutter project can't run in debug mode.

This error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* What went wrong:

Unable to start the daemon process.

This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.

For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.

Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/userguide/gradle_daemon.html

Process command line: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_221\bin\java.exe -Xmx1536M -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\ajoris\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.2-all\9st6wgf78h16so49nn74lgtbb\gradle-5.6.2\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.2.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.6.2

Please read the following process output to find out more:

-----------------------

Error occurred during initialization of VM

Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc."


* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Is there something missing in the settings on my `new laptop`? I tried to `clean project`, `upgrade flutter` but always fail. Sorry for new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just sorted this on my side. I was unable to see any devices and when starting VS code it would warn me with a pop up "Flutter error Unable to start the daemon process" underneath it stated it was dart causing the error.

I cd to flutter package where I am using the stable repo, I did a git fetch. then went bank to my project and ran flutter pub get. I closed and opened the project and now I see devices and have no pup up warnings. I did see a pop up "dart has been updated" message.

Answer (score 16):

What actually worked for me is, In windows 10 just turn off your mobile hotspot and run the app again. I think it's a glitch/bug in windows 10.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes turning off Wifi Hotspot of my Dell and restarting the laptop solved the issue

Answer (score 7):

The solution to this problem is deactivating windows hotspot before running build or app compilation.

Don't delete anything or file, just build the app with mobile hotspot turned off.'

its a windows 10 bug that start without any reason. i refreshed my windows and this started

Flutter or Android Applications

Comment: Yes turning off Wifi Hotspot of my Dell and restarting the laptop solved the issue

Answer (score 4):

The general steps I would use are:

1. run `flutter doctor` in terminal
2. if you are using an emulator make sure it has enough space (often it needs a restart to clear junk files created upon consecutive deploys)
3. if the gradle files have been modified it is recommended to open them with Android Studio (Android folder of the application). If anything is missing the IDE will prompt you to install the missing dependencies.
   Hope it helps

Comment: No.1 I already do it every time and always same output. I use emulator and real device but always same error. No.3 I use Visual Studio Code

Comment: @BerthoJoris I also use VS Code but Android Studio has some extra features especially when it comes to gradle. If you have it already installed (to avoid losing time with installs) I suggest opening the project's Android folder and then double click the gradle file. 
It might pop some install / fix prompt

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ok I will try open with Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above methods but sadly none of them worked. What eventually worked for me was too simple.

first try all the suggested solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio) and if it doesn't work

try to disable mobile firewall, actually I discovered that it's a windows 10 bug because disabling mobile hotspot just until you build or compile your project then you can reenable it without any problem .

**Step 1**: Open the Registry Editor on your Windows 10 computer. To do this, just press the Windows + R keys on your keyboard. In the Run dialog box, type “Regedit” and hit enter. This will open the Registry Editor window.

**Step 2**: In the Registry Editor, navigate to the following location:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE SOFTWARE Policies Microsoft WindowsNetwork Connections

**Step 3**: In the Network Connections key, on the right-side pane, right-click anywhere in the empty area and select New > DWORD (32-bit) Value.

**Step 4**: Name the newly created registry “NC_ShowSharedAccessUI” and keep its value as “0” to disable the Mobile Hotspot feature on your laptop.

**Step 5**: To enable the feature, just change the value of the NC_ShowSharedAccessUI registry from 0 to 1 and the feature will be enabled again.

When the functionality has been disabled, the feature will still appear in the Network & Internet settings but it cannot be enabled or configured. To use the feature, the registry needs to be edited again and enable the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post what solved for me.

```
flutter clean

flutter run
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a memory problem.
In your project folder, Go to android/gradle.properties.
Change the line

From:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M

To:

> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024M

Save the gradle.properties file and try to run debugging again.

That Worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Non of the solution in here worked for me. running my vscode or android studio as an administrator solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it Is bcoz of the .gradle file in C:drive.
1.Locate to the .gradle folder (usually in C:\users\your_username)
2.Delete the .gradle folder once located.
2.Locate to your flutter project folder 
2.Locate to android 
3.Run gradlew clean 
4.Run gradlew build
5.now run your app...It worked for me

Comment: pretty sure that this wont help with his heap problem on running the java interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above methods but sadly none of them worked. What eventually worked for me was simple.

There has been a lot of problem with emulator configuration and sometimes it crashes for a lot of reasons. For the above problem what I recommend is, delete the current emulator but remember the settings like API version and all and make a new emulator.

This worked for me fine!

Answer (score 0):

1. Close Android studio
2. Delete your ".gradle" folder
3. Open android studio as administrator and allow project to build.

Answer (score 0):

For my case i had `--no-sound-null-safety` in the **Dart: Flutter Additional Args** ( go to vscode settings under extensions dart ). I deleted it, deleted the web folder in the project ( i was working on the app only ) then reloaded vscode. the error was gone afterwards

Answer (score 0):

go to **C:\Program Files\nodejs**

Open **npm, npm.cmd, npx, npx.cmd**
then change the **prefix -g** to **prefix --location=global**

still if this did not work,
go to **android studio** click on **build**, then click **clear project**.

I also faced this issue and this step resolved problem. Still if this did not work out let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your system is running out of memory. Close some programs and free up memory and try again .The problem is that OpenJDK platform binary opens many instances which eats up system memory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved the issue by just upgrading Flutter:

```
$ flutter channel stable
$ flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to `file/setting/build,execution,deployment/gradle`, and there where Gradle user home: pass static address.

For example, my address is `C:/Users/Admin/.gradle`.

After applying if runs OK.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple solution.
Uninstall the app from your device .
Then restart the PC .

Answer (score -1):

- First of all Uninstall the application from emulator.
- then wipe all data from the emulator.
- Sometimes turning off mobile hotspot will do the work.
- After turning off if not work then restart the pc or a laptop. Don't turn on mobile hotspot and run `flutter run`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32167185)