# The Flutter Daemon failed to start: VSCode

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, visual-studio-code

I am receiving this error each time I open VSCode on Windows 11

> The Flutter Daemon failed to start.

along with a notice telling me that packages are missing or out of date. I also receive an error when opening Andriod Studio that states:

> Flutter device daemon #1 exited (exit code 255), stderr: Checking Dart SDK version... was unexpected at this time.

This only started today, everything has been working perfectly for weeks before now.

Using `flutter run` in Powershell runs the application on both an emulator and a physical device with no issues, the problem appears to be with VSCode and/or Android Studio.

I have tried every fix I could find on here and other places including:

1. A full Flutter reinstall in a new directory, in a new drive with a change of the PATH variables
2. Deleting my .gradle folder followed by another full deletion and reinstall
3. Running `flutter doctor -v` which returns a full set of green checks
4. Running `flutter clean` and `flutter upgrade`

VSCode gives me the following log on load:

````
[17:46:27] [General] [Info] Environment PATH:
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\system32
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\dotnet\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     D:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     D:\Program Files\PuTTY\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     D:\Program Files\nodejs\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS\system32
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\atom\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\nvs\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\pault\AppData\Roaming\npm
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Program Files\heroku\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\pault\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     D:\src\flutter\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info] Took 306ms to search for projects (5 levels)
[17:46:27] [General] [Info] Took 3ms to filter out excluded projects (0 exclusion rules)
[17:46:27] [General] [Info] Found Flutter project at E:\Flutter\test_app:
            Mobile? true
            Web? false
            Create Trigger? false
            Flutter Repo? false
[17:46:27] [General] [Info] Searching for flutter.bat
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     Looking for flutter.bat in:
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\tools\flutter
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\tools\flutter\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         E:\Flutter\test_app
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         E:\Flutter\test_app\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\src\flutter\bin\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         E:\Flutter\test_app\.flutter
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         E:\Flutter\test_app\.flutter\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         E:\Flutter\test_app\vendor\flutter
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         E:\Flutter\test_app\vendor\flutter\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\flutter-sdk
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\flutter-sdk\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         /google/flutter
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         \google\flutter\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\PuTTY\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\PuTTY\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\nodejs\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\nodejs\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\atom\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\nvs\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\nvs\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Roaming\npm
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\heroku\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\src\flutter\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\tools\flutter\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\src\flutter\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\tools\flutter
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\src\flutter
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     Found at C:\tools\flutter
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path C:\tools\flutter for flutter.bat
[17:46:27] [General] [Info] Searching for dart.exe
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     Looking for dart.exe in:
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\system32\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\PuTTY\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\PuTTY\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\nodejs\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\nodejs\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\atom\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\nvs\
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\nvs\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Roaming\npm
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\heroku\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\pault\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         D:\src\flutter\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]         C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     Found at C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[17:46:27] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk for dart.exe
[17:46:27] [General] [Info] Experiment random number is 98 for experiment 'sdkDaps'. Experiment is enabled for <= 10
[17:46:27] [General] [Info] Experiment 'sdkDaps' does not apply and will not be activated
[17:46:27] [General] [Info] !! PLEASE REVIEW THIS LOG FOR SENSITIVE INFORMATION BEFORE SHARING !!

Dart Code extension: 3.48.3
Flutter extension: 3.48.0 (not activated)

App: Visual Studio Code
Version: 1.71.0
Platform: win

Workspace type: Flutter
Analyzer type: LSP
Multi-root?: false

Dart SDK:
    Loc: C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
    Ver: 2.16.2
Flutter SDK:
    Loc: C:\tools\flutter
    Ver: 2.10.5

HTTP_PROXY: undefined
NO_PROXY: undefined
[17:46:27] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] Spawning C:\tools\flutter\bin\flutter.bat with args ["daemon"]
[17:46:27] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  in C:\tools\flutter
[17:46:27] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code"}}
[17:46:28] [FlutterDaemon] [Info]     PID: 11176
[17:46:28] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ==> [{"id":"1","method":"emulator.getEmulators"}]
[17:46:28] [DevTools] [Info] Spawning C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe with args ["devtools","--machine","--try-ports","10","--allow-embedding"]
[17:46:28] [DevTools] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code"}}
[17:46:28] [DevTools] [Info]     PID: 11176
[17:46:28] [Analyzer] [Info] Spawning C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe with args ["language-server","--protocol=lsp","--client-id=VS-Code","--client-version=3.48.3"]
[17:46:28] [Analyzer] [Info]     PID: 2456
[17:46:28] [General] [Info] Returning cached results for project search
[17:46:28] [General] [Info] Activating Flutter extension for Flutter project...
[17:46:28] [General] [Info] Extension:Startup timing: 401ms
[17:46:28] [General] [Info] Found 1 folders requiring "pub get":
    E:\Flutter\test_app
[17:46:28] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> Content-Length: 6247
[17:46:28] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"method":"initialize","params":{"processId":11176,"clientInfo":{"name":"Visual Studio Code","version":"1.71.0"},"locale":"en-gb","rootPath":"e:\\Flutter\\test_app","rootUri":"file:///e%3A/Flutter/test_app","capabilities":{"workspace":{"applyEdit":true,"workspaceEdit":{"documentChanges":true,"resourceOperations":["create","rename","delete"],"failureHandling":"textOnlyTransactional","normalizesLineEndings":true,"changeAnnotationSupport":{"groupsOnLabel":true}},"configur…
[17:46:28] [General] [Info] Caching Pub package names from pub.dev...
[17:46:28] [General] [Info] !! PLEASE REVIEW THIS LOG FOR SENSITIVE INFORMATION BEFORE SHARING !!

Dart Code extension: 3.48.3
Flutter extension: 3.48.0 (activated)

App: Visual Studio Code
Version: 1.71.0
Platform: win

Workspace type: Flutter
Analyzer type: LSP
Multi-root?: false

Dart SDK:
    Loc: C:\tools\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
    Ver: 2.16.2
Flutter SDK:
    Loc: C:\tools\flutter
    Ver: 2.10.5

HTTP_PROXY: undefined
NO_PROXY: undefined
[17:46:28] [FlutterDaemon] [Error] Checking Dart SDK version... 
<< was unexpected at this time.```
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010134/flutter-error-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process. Please check it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Daemon failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68766600/flutter-daemon-failed-to-start)

Answer (score 1):

I delete the --no-sound-null-safety Flutter additional arg, then restart VS Code and then re-add the --no-sound-null-safety additional arg since it is required for my app to be able to start.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the comment suggestions provided a fix, I had already been into those questions and attempted the fixes provided.

I took another shot today and eventually found the issue. At some point the Dart and Flutter SDK paths inside VSCode became corrupted, it ended up simply being a case of going to settings and editing the `settings.json` file to point to the new locations, this has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When i run 'flutter doctor' it give me all green checks. but vscode gave me 'flutter daemon failed to start' error.
I think it was a problem of settings and paths.
So, I recommend you reinstall vscode(stable) and init your vscode settings.
I worked for me.

1. Remove Vscode and settings(something like cache)
2. Reinstall Vscode and flutter extensions.(It includes Dart pkg now(2023.1) )
3. If still raise this error, check your configs about tool_state of flutter

   In my case(M1 MacOS) typed this code and worked!
   "sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/{user_name}/.config/flutter/tool_state"

Answer (score 0):

please change flutter sdk path and update path , enviroment variables and restart your system issue will be resolved , else download new setup of flutter and install