# getting error create new project in android studio

Tags: android

hello guys i updated my android studio 4.0 to 4.1

getting error after updating android studio build.gradle. i tried completely uninstall android studio but didn't worked again

log

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=GB -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Onur\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin\6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0

-----------------------
Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:
 - gradle.properties in project root directory
```

And memory usage %100. i tried exit android studio but java jdk exe uses computer ram %100 again

what's problem? someone help please? i want to use this project my website [başvuru tarihi](https://basvurutarihi.com)

Comment: Try updating your Java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio

Answer (score 0):

Your computer probably does not have the right specifications to run android studio. You need more RAM and processing speed