# How do I run/build my app from Android Studio 4.1 64 bit Windows 10 laptop to Android 3.6 42 bit Windows 7 laptop

Tags: android-studio, windows-7, 32bit-64bit

I've run into a problem. My previous laptop Acer Aspire R7 Windows 10 64 bit laptop crashed. This was the only laptop I had until I was given another one, but it's a Windows 7 32 bit Samsung. Anyway I was able to install an older version of Android Studio, but I've now run into problems. When I try to open my app that I created from the previous laptop it keeps telling me
"Gradle project sync failed". Basic functionality(e.g editing and debugging) will not work properly" and it says "Kotlin not configured".

There's nothing wrong with my code, so that's all I can say is the problem. I don't know what to do now, because this is app was how I made my income and now I can't work on it.

**UPDATE**

So I've made a bit more progress now, but i still have problems.

This is what my log shows when I try to clean or rebuild my project

```
    Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Users\Rodney SA\Downloads\android-studio-ide-192.6241897-windows32\android-studio\jre\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\Rodney SA\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.1.1-all\cfmwm155h49vnt3hynmlrsdst\gradle-6.1.1\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.1.1
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap

-----------------------
Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:
 - gradle.properties in project root directory
```

Comment: Upload your build.gradle

Comment: That's a problem. It only says "Starting daemon" and "MyNotepad(my app name) app failed to build". That's all I have

Comment: Go to directory of your app open build.gradle in notepad copy the code and paste it here

Comment: I pasted the gradle in my updated question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Gradle project "Unable to start the daemon process /initialization of VM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio)

Answer (score 0):

“Gradle sync failed” is a very common error in Android studio.

It happens generally when your project is lacking some files which need to be downloaded.

First go to File>Setting>search Gradle keyword and uncheck offline work

Make sure you have enough high speed data

Goto Tools>Android>Sync Projects Gradle Files

It will automatically download the necessary file.

Android studio is a very data consuming IDE you will have to face frequent updates.