# Building Projects in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following error when I try to build my project in Android Studio:

```
Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=GB -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\ariel\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin\6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5 
Please read the following process output to find out more: ----------------------- FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind * Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. * Exception is: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:61) at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:41) at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.FileLockCommunicator. (FileLockCommunicator.java:51) at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.getCommunicator(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:263) at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.reservePort(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:255) at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:108) at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:95) at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:90) at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.updateFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:51) at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.update(SimpleStateCache.java:87) at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator$1.create(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:50) at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.doUpdate(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:67) at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.update(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:47) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.store(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:232) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater.onStart(DaemonRegistryUpdater.java:80) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon.start(Daemon.java:171) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonMain.doAction(DaemonMain.java:125) at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:50) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60) at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37) at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22) Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method) at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:84) at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:93) at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:392) at java.net.DatagramSocket. (DatagramSocket.java:242) at java.net.DatagramSocket. (DatagramSocket.java:299) at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.FileLockCommunicator. (FileLockCommunicator.java:49) ... 22 more * 
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (4 m 57 s 695 ms)
```

Please how can I correct it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio Gradle project "Unable to start the daemon process /initialization of VM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio)

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/q/25009717/15403976