# android studio - Gradle sync failed Error - occurred during initialization

Tags: android, android-studio

Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Program Files\gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin\6nifqtx7604sqp1q6g8wikw7p\gradle-6.5\lib\gradle-launcher-6.5.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.5
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
-----------------------
Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:
- gradle.properties in project root directory
Consult IDE log fo... (show balloon)

Comment: Please take the time to write an actual question. Yes, that might be implied by posting the error. But a simple search reveals a lot of information on remedies for your problem, and it would help solving your specific case if you could indicate somehow what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of
[Android Studio Gradle project "Unable to start the daemon process /initialization of VM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio)

If all else fails delete the .gradle and .idea file.
Close Android Studio
Open the project up again.

Answer (score 0):

first of all use proxy or some dns like [shecan](https://shecan.ir/) cause we are forbidden in Iran, then try to sync and build Gradle ;
in some cases clean the project then rebuild will be work !