# After installed of new Windows and Andriod Studio, cannot run existing project

Tags: android

After installed of new Windows and Andriod Studio,the existing project cannot run now. Please help!

The error message is as below.

> Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by
> incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an unrecognized
> jvm option is used. Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the
> daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.1.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
> Process command line:
> C:\Users\samkong.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_322\bin\java.exe
> --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx2048m--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED -Dfile.encoding=x-windows-950 -Duser.country=HK -Duser.language=zh -Duser.variant -cp D:\Android\DeliveryApp api level24\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.1.1-all\cfmwm155h49vnt3hynmlrsdst\gradle-6.1.1\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar
> org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.1.1 Please read
> the following process output to find out more:
> ----------------------- Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
> Unrecognized option: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
>
> ----------------------- Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:
>
> - gradle.properties in project root directory

Comment: Maybe this could Help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009717/android-studio-gradle-project-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-initializatio

Comment: The error message says it's failing to start gradle (the project builder) because it's failing to start the JVM, in turn because the JVM doesn't like the option: `--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED` that's in the `gradle.properties` file in project root directory. Perhaps it's trying to run an old JVM that predates the `--add-opens` option, in which case it'd help to update the JVM or to point gradle to the right JVM among the installed JVMs.

Comment: I think `--add-opens` is a Java 9 feature (i.e. JDK 1.9), while the error message you got implies it's trying to run JDK 1.8.0.